# Why when I use stack() the number of rows increase?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I tried to merge the two columns begin and end to Flag and Timestamp with this piece of code:

```
print(df_DisponibilityAlarm.shape)

df_DisponibilityAlarm = (df_DisponibilityAlarm.stack()
 .rename_axis([None, 'Flag'])
 .reset_index(level=1, name='Timestamp'))

print(df_DisponibilityAlarm.shape)
```

The result is :

```
                         begin                          end
0                          NaN  2019-10-21  07:48:28.272688
1                          NaN  2019-10-21  07:48:28.449916
2  2019-10-21  07:48:26.740378                          NaN
3  2019-10-21  07:48:26.923764                          NaN
4                          NaN  2019-10-21  07:48:41.689466
5  2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045                          NaN
6                          NaN  2019-10-21  07:58:00.774449
7  2019-10-21  07:57:59.223986                          NaN
8                          NaN  2019-10-21  08:32:37.004455
9  2019-10-21  08:32:35.755252                          NaN

(13129, 2)
(13140, 2)

    Flag                    Timestamp
0    end  2019-10-21  07:48:28.272688
1    end  2019-10-21  07:48:28.449916
2  begin  2019-10-21  07:48:26.740378
3  begin  2019-10-21  07:48:26.923764
4    end  2019-10-21  07:48:41.689466
5  begin  2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045
6    end  2019-10-21  07:58:00.774449
7  begin  2019-10-21  07:57:59.223986
8    end  2019-10-21  08:32:37.004455
9  begin  2019-10-21  08:32:35.755252
```

It works ! But when I looked closely, I see when I use "stack()" the number of the rows increase... I don't understand why, can you explain me please ? I need this to validate my starting hypothesis.

Comment: Look at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) about how this behaves. `stack()` will "stack" column values into long format as apposed to `unstack()`, which reshapes DataFrame into wide format. In particular, pay attention to the examples in the docs to visually see what happens.

Comment: @Ukrainian-serge Thanks for your help. So my question is, how to check if I have all the data since the result is different thanks to stack() ?

Comment: Your question is not reproducible, meaning I cant just copy and paste and reprocude your results. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to do that. As I copy and paste your examples it is not reproducible.

Comment: @Ukrainian-serge any idea ? since my new post

Comment: Read below answer  **`.stack()` does not "stack" `begin`/`end` column values that contain `NaN`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDITED

Inherently, `stack()` function makes your dataset longer **BUT** as you can see in your sample printout:

**rows that contained `NaN` are not included after stacking.** <-------------

---

Consider the test case below, added `TEST_VALUE`:

```
begin,end
NaN,2019-10-21  07:48:28.272688
NaN,2019-10-21  07:48:28.449916
2019-10-21  07:48:26.740378,NaN
2019-10-21  07:48:26.923764,NaN
NaN,2019-10-21  07:48:41.689466
2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045,TEST_VALUE
NaN,2019-10-21  07:58:00.774449
2019-10-21  07:57:59.223986,NaN
NaN,2019-10-21  08:32:37.004455
2019-10-21  08:32:35.755252,NaN

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',') 

print(df.shape)
print(df.stack().shape)
print(df.stack())

(10, 2)
(11, )
0  end      2019-10-21  07:48:28.272688
1  end      2019-10-21  07:48:28.449916
2  begin    2019-10-21  07:48:26.740378
3  begin    2019-10-21  07:48:26.923764
4  end      2019-10-21  07:48:41.689466
5  begin    2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045
   end                       TEST_VALUE
6  end      2019-10-21  07:58:00.774449
7  begin    2019-10-21  07:57:59.223986
8  end      2019-10-21  08:32:37.004455
9  begin    2019-10-21  08:32:35.755252

# this part is strange
print(df.stack()[5])
begin    2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045
end                       TEST_VALUE
dtype: object
```

*It's pretty strange how index `5` is as compared to the rest and I don't have an answer as to why it is a type of multiindex and the rest in the Series are not, but let us continue...*

As you can see this added an extra row for `TEST_VALUE` and AGAIN any value with `NaN` is not included in the stacked version.

I would "standardize" or make sure your data contains either `NaN` or date, or fill your `NaN` with some other value using `fillna()`.

If you wanted to keep your data the way it is, you could also process your data in chunks to zero in on **WHERE**(in my sample its `TEST_VALUE`) the data is not uniformed like so:

```
# read df in as an iterator with chunks

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(
                    sep=',', 
                    chunksize=3  # change this to whatever chunksize you need
)

def test_chunks(df_iterator):
    """
    Function that compares original df chunk size shape to stacked chunksize shape
    Returns: original chunk where there is a mismatch in shapes
    """
    for df_chunk in df_iterator:
        original = df_chunk.shape[0]
        stacked = df_chunk.stack().shape[0]
        if original != stacked:
            return df_chunk

bad_chunk = test_chunks(df1)
print(bad_chunk)

                         begin                          end
3  2019-10-21  07:48:26.923764                          NaN
4                          NaN  2019-10-21  07:48:41.689466
5  2019-10-21  07:48:37.306045                   TEST_VALUE
```

So, although I cannot be sure because I don't have access to your full data, my verdict would be that it is a data uniformity issue.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: any ideo since my new post ?